# Server Name on Java Application Home Page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, web-applications

My application is running on Tomcat server and I want to show the server name on which it is hosted on the home page.

It is a java based application. What I have done presently is as follows:

In my Interceptor class which extends from HandlerInterceptorAdapter(Spring Framework), I have the preHandle method. I have written:

```
 String serverName = request.getServerName();
 session.setAttribute(ApplicationConstants.SERVER_INFO,serverName);
```

In my jsp page,

```
<%session.getAttribute(ApplicationConstants.SERVER_INFO)%>
```

I am able to see the server name  (example: localhost.abc.com)

Is this the right approach? Guidance will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: session.getServletContext().getContextPath() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting it per session, you can set it in `ServletContext` instead

Comment: I did that. Thanks. I am setting it to ServletContext and then retrieving the attribute in my jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required to take server name from every request, manually set the server name as a context parameter in web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>serverName</param-name>
<param-value>ABC</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and get it in init method .

```
String serverName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("ABC");
```

and set this value in context.

Comment: In this case I will have different server names for different regions and different environment. So will this be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

**request** object is available on the JSP page implicitly, so you can get rid of session scope and simply use:

```
<%=request.getServerName() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the approach and used the Java7 feature java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost() to get the host name.